# OutOfMemoryError in Android App

Tags: android, out-of-memory, logcat

Can anybody explain to me this LogCat output and how to solve it? I was testing my Android app with my cellphone (Samsung Galaxy Nexus) and just like that; the system forced detention and printed this in the LogCat...

```
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:301)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:326)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:894)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:379)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at tian.proto.galeriaImagenes$ImageAdapter.getView(galeriaImagenes.java:169)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
04-17 09:43:09.189: E/AndroidRuntime(1194):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the bitmap at runtime, you can scale it down as you read it from the device using [this technique](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html). If you're loading it from the `res` directory, you may just need to scale it down using an image editor. Either way, the image is apparently too large to fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use `ImageView.setImageURI` to load the image.

Now many images, especially taken by higher resolution cameras (or phones) , images easily take up far more space than actually needed to display them on the screen.

When you try to directly load them into a Bitmap, your app will run out of memory and crash.
Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object#823966) or the answer by @oakleaf for the link to the Android Developer Training about using large bitmaps.